# What's the exact distinction between the FOR loop and the WHILE Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I understand that loops are an integral part of any programming language. They help us to iterate tasks that are repetitive. But I don't seem to understand why these 2 loops are required seperately. Can't just one of them do the job? I have tried both loops and still can't seem to understand how are these 2 loops different and where it is better to use which loop ! Please someone explain to me in detail with example!

I have tried many programs like factorial, sum of a list and prime numbers, using both loops but I'm unable to understand where to use which loop because surely there must be some rule of thumb to decide where to use which loop ! I expect someone to clear this query of mine with example.

Comment: A `for` loop is basically just a convenience for loops involving iterators. See https://github.com/brettcannon/desugar#for-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually not a question.  If you need to run a fixed number of loops, or you need to do something once for each item in a collection, then you want a `for` loop.  Anything based on a counter uses a `for` loop.  If you need to loop until some specific condition happens, or loop forever, then you want a `while`.

```
# Print 5 numbers.
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

It's usually obvious when you've made the wrong choice:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

That's a lot of extra typing to do what the `for` loop does.

```
lst = [5,4,3,2,1]
for n in lst:
    print("This element is",n)
```

But here is a case where `while` is better:

```
while True:
    s = input("Type q to quit: ")
    if s == 'q':
        break
```

Comment: In your last example it's not "better" to use a while-loop, it's just the only solution.

Comment: It's not the only solution. `for s in iter(lambda: input("..."), "q"): ...`. (I'm hesitant to say that *any* `while` loop can be converted to a `for` loop using this trick, but a good number of them can be.)

Answer (score 1):

`For` ends by itself when it comes to the end of iterable 
`While` ends when its condition is False

if there is some condition you need to check on every loop you need to use `While` 
if there is an iterable object you need to iterate on you've to use `for`

Answer (score 0):

The main distinction would be that it isn't necessary to specifically iterate a 'for loop', but if a 'while loop' isn't iterated, it becomes an infinite loop.

For example:

```py
#In for loop
n = 5
for i in range (n):
    print(i)
#This program will print the numbers from 0 to 4
```

but if you do something similar with a while loop like this:

```py
n = 5
i = 0
while i in range (n):
    print(i)
```

then this will just print '0' and will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In a computer programming language, iteration statements like for loop and while loop and more are used for repeated execution of the instruction in a program. Both for loop and while loop is used to execute the statements repeatedly while the program runs.
The major difference between for loop  and while loop is that for loop is used when the number of iterations is known, whereas execution is done in a while loop until the statement in the program is proved wrong. For loop also provide a concise way of writing the loop structure.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is indeed not necessary. But most loops involving iterators are *simpler* to write using a `for` loop than an equivalent `while` loop.

https://github.com/brettcannon/desugar provides many examples of "desugaring" various Python constructs into equivalent, more "basic" constructs. `for` loops can be converted to `while` loops by manually iterating over the given iterable. The following example is from https://github.com/brettcannon/desugar#for-.

```
for a in b:
    c
```

becomes

```
# next and iter are built-in functions, so there's no concern
# that we're just hiding a for loop here somewhere.
_iter = iter(b)
while True:
    try:
        a = next(_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        c
del _iter
```

The `for` loop automatically gets an iterator for the iterable, calls `next`, and handles `StopIteration` to terminate the loop.

Which would you prefer to write?